# Using Laravel's foreignIdFor method and create a composite unique key

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

Following the syntax below, I can easily create a composite unique key based on the fields `name` and `bakery_id`:

```php
Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('bakery_id')->constrained();
    $table->string('name', 30);
    $table->boolean('enabled')->default(true);
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->unique(['bakery_id', 'name']);
});
```

When I use the "`foreignIdFor()`" method instead of "`foreignId()`", is there a way to programmatically determine the name of the column?

```php
Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignIdFor(Bakery::class)->constrained();
    $table->string('name', 30);
    $table->boolean('enabled')->default(true);
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->unique(['???', 'name']);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just need to capture the column definition and use that:

```
Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $colDef = $table->foreignIdFor(Bakery::class)->constrained();
    $table->string('name', 30);
    $table->boolean('enabled')->default(true);
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->unique([$colDef->name, 'name']);
});
```

Comment: Can't you just use `$colDef->name`? Also, not worth a separate answer, but `(new Bakery)->getForeignKey()` will also work.

Comment: @miken32 Cleaned up the attribute

Comment: How does the `down()` method look like? As for the dropping indexes ...

Comment: When tried the above answer.
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'foreign' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `table_name` add unique `index_name`(`foreign`));

As suggested by @miken32 (new Bakery)->getForeignKey() Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In laravel 8 foreignIdFor, you can pass primary key for the second argument

```
/**
* Create a foreign ID column for the given model.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|string  $model
* @param  string|null  $column
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Schema\ForeignIdColumnDefinition
*/
public function foreignIdFor($model, $column = null)
{
    if (is_string($model)) {
        $model = new $model;
    }

    return $model->getKeyType() === 'int' && $model->getIncrementing()
                ? $this->foreignId($column ?: $model->getForeignKey())
                : $this->foreignUuid($column ?: $model->getForeignKey());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in laravel 8 and above you can specify the column name as a second paramete:

```
$table->foreignIdFor(Bakery::class,'bakery_id')->constrained();
```

and then:

```
$table->unique([bakery_id, 'name']);

Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->id();
$table->foreignIdFor(Bakery::class,'bakery_id')->constrained();//pass the column name as second param
$table->string('name', 30);
$table->boolean('enabled')->default(true);
$table->timestamps();

$table->unique(['bakery_id', 'name']);//column name
```

});

for short code you can chain the **->unique()** function

```
$table->unique([bakery_id, 'name']);

Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->id();
$table->foreignIdFor(Bakery::class,'bakery_id')->unique()->constrained();//pass the column name as second param and chain the unique function
$table->string('name', 30)->unique();//chain the unique function
$table->boolean('enabled')->default(true);
$table->timestamps();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question but maybe this might help

```
Schema::create('product_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id();
   // $table->foreignIdFor(Bakery::class)->constrained();
   $table->unsignedInteger('bakery_id')->nullable();
   $table->foreign('bakery_id')->references('id')->on('bake')->onDelete('cascade');
   $table->string('name', 30);
   $table->boolean('enabled')->default(true);
   $table->timestamps();

   $table->unique(['bakery_id', 'name']);
});
```